# Device Login Page is not coming when entering TFS (Team Foundation Server) URL in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs, azure-devops, team-explorer-everywhere

I am trying to set up my Eclipse with my TFS Project (Team Explorer Everywhere). I am following the below documentation:
https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/java/eclipsegit/
I am able to install the TFS Plugin. But as per the Step 10 in the documentation, I am not able to get the Device Login window post entering the TFS URL. After clicking on OK, the next expected window is not getting populated. The URL is correct as I am able to access the same through the browser. I have also tried by entering my credentials but still no luck. Can anyone help or suggest if I am missing anything.

Comment: I tested your problem, but it cannot be reproduced. The Device Login windows can be [displayed normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L5JF.png). You can try to reinstall the TEE plugin or repair Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. There was an issue with the plugin. I used TFS 14.134.0 version instead of TFS 14.135.0 and I was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the Device Login windows does not pop up normally, it could be an issue with the plugin.

You can try to uninstall the TFS plugin and install TFS 14.135.0 to solve the problem.